# DataFrame: Filtrar columna a partir de datos de referencia

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Dispongo del dataframe **portfolio_df** con los siguientes identificadores en la columna "Ticker"

```
portfolio_df["Ticker"].unique()
array(['TrueValue ', 'ValorRelativo ', 'Advantage ', 'Acatis ', 'EPSV ',
       'DedaloPP ', 'NexusPP ', 'iberdrola', 'telefonica', 'renta_4'],
      dtype=object)
```

En la variable **combinacion** almacenamos los siguientes identificadores

```
['Acatis', 'Avantage', 'TrueValue', 'ValorRelativo']
```

Necesito obtener un dataframe filtrado con los valores de todas las filas que en la columna **ticker**, tengan uno de los identificadores de la lista **combinacion**. Para ello he probado laopción siguiente.

```
df_filtrado = portfolio_df[portfolio_df['Ticker'].isin(combinacion)]
```

El resulatado es un dataframe vacío
Empty DataFrame

```
Columns: [Acquisition Date, Ticker, Quantity, Unit Cost, Cost Basis]
Index: []
```

¿Cual puede ser la causa?. ¿Hay alguna otra manera de conseguir el resultado deseado?.
Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

En el link
[Enlace a muestra_datos.xlsx](https://github.com/akitxu/Aprendiendo-GitHub)

se encuentra el fichero **muestra_datos.xlsx** 
Co esta sentencia, creo el dtaframe **portfolio_df**

```
portfolio_df = pd.read_excel('./Ficheros/muestra_datos.xlsx', sheet_name='Hoja1')
```

Comment: No parece que estuvieras haciendo nada equivocado en el código. ¿Podrías compartir una muestra de los datos?

Comment: En el enlace  "https://github.com/akitxu/Aprendiendo-GitHub", se encuentra el fichero Excel  muestra_datos.xlsx, del que importo los datos del dataframe portfolio_df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que esa columna de la excel contiene espacios al final de las palabras en algunas de sus celdas, por lo que no coinciden ya con los valores especificados en tu lista.

Una posible solución, aparte de preprocesar los datos de esa columna para "arreglarlos", podría ser usar esta otra condición para el filtrado:

```
df.Ticker.srt.strip().isin(combinacion)
```

Comment: Efectivamente, este era el problema, A veces uno se olvida de que para analizar un problema, se debe empezar por eliminar las posibles causas más simples. Muchas gracias